# Проблема с меню в Android приложении

Tags: java, android, menu

Создал новое меню. Вот файл ресурсов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="Настройки"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/save_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Сохранить"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/open_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title="Открыть"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Вот код активности:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Вот структура проекта:

[image: структура]

При запуске приложения меню появляется, однако есть проблема... Пункты меню не высвечиваются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал и следующий синтаксис: app:showAsAction. Тоже не помагает.

Comment: Похоже на проблему с темой. Попробуйте удалить свою из манифеста.